# Weierstrass non-differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-sum

In our analysis book it says that the following function proposed by Weierstrass is continuous everywhere, but nowhere differentiable.

$$f(x)=\sum _{n=1}^{∞}\frac{1}{2^n}\cos \left(3^nx\right)$$

The series must converge because it is the product of a convergent series and an alternating series, but the exponent inside cosine makes it tricky to evaluate.

When I graph it, it looks very strange indeed.

[graph of function (n=1 to 100)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tQOv.png)

Would this be considered fractal? Is it differentiable analytically?

Comment: Related, the [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function)

Comment: I've always thought of it as a fractal myself, but I'm not sure if that squares up with the official definition of the term.

Comment: A fractal is a mathematical set that exhibits a repeating pattern displayed at every scale. This function definitely has that.

Comment: It's actually not quite alternating; the signs oscillate but not in a regular manner except for particular values of $x$. But since $|\cos| \leq 1$ it's easy to see that it is absolutely convergent. Also, a finite truncation like you plotted is actually still differentiable, but the derivative is very oscillatory. The infinite sum will not be differentiable (because $\frac{3}{2} \geq 1$).

Comment: It's not an alternating series (the cosine term will be close to one for large n). It converges uniformly, because the cosine is bounded and the other factor decreases rapidly.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is a Weierstrass function, which are of the form

$$W(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a^k\cos(b^n\pi x)$$

Your function is of this form with $a=\tfrac12$ and $b=3$, since then $W(\frac x\pi)=f(x)$. Weierstrass functions are nowhere differentiable yet continuous, and so is your $f$. A quote from wikipedia:

> Like fractals, the function exhibits self-similarity: every zoom is similar to the global plot.

So yes, it would be considered a fractal.

Read more about Weierstrass functions [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function).